# Unlock iPhone 3GS iOS 5.0.1 with baseband 06.15.00

Tags: jailbreak

I recently updated my iPhone 3GS to iOS 5.0.1, and the baseband got updated to 06.15.00. I jailbroke it using redsn0w 0.9.10b1.

Now no matter what I try, I'm not able to unlock my iPhone. I tried installing Ultrasn0w, but that's not working.

I suspect that this is happening since I didnt preserve the baseband.

I'd be very very thankful if anyone can tell me how to proceed right now. I'm stuck and I'm really in need of help. Please.

Comment: Be careful! If your 3GS was made after the 30th or so week of 2011, you will brick your 3GS by flashing to 06.15.00

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this](http://www.iphonejailbreak.me/jailbreak-and-unlock-iphone-3gs-ios-5-0-1-using-sn0wbreeze-custom-firmware-and-ipad-baseband-6-15-00/) tutorial before. In fact, I'm using it *right now* to unlock my boss's iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable the option "Install iPad baseband" in redsn0w first before running ultasn0w - note that because you are already on 06.15.00 without preserving your baseband, can not go back. Using Ultrasn0w may also cause you to lose GPS functionality. As a general note, be very careful with future updates.

Comment: Will any version of redsn0w do? Or should I download the latest version?

Comment: I'm asking this because I enabled the "Install iPad baseband" after an unseccesful unlock attempt first. But even then I wasn't able to unlock my iPhone...

Comment: You'd probably want the latest version of redsn0w. Re run the latest version with install iPad baseband enabled. Then you should see Cydia installed. Within Cydia download and install ultrasn0w